# How to stop mail app from sending me an e-mail with "reply all"

Tags: mail.app

When I want to do "reply-all" to a message that involves multiple people, the mail app includes myself in the list of recipients. Is there a way to turn off this feature?

Comment: Is the email being received via a forward or alias?  What you're describing is not normal behavior unless the "from" address of the "reply all" is different than where the email was addressed originally.

Comment: @Tyson There is an alias system. Each user has a username, but using name.lastname@... works too. That might be the problem. I'll contact our system administrator.

Comment: Correct. Reply all removes the address that it will be sending from, but if it actually sending from jon.doe@ it doesn't know that that jon@ is the same person.

Answer (score 1):

Like Tyson said, normally this doesn't happen, but maybe your Mail.app is configured to send you a copy of your mails sent.

Go to Mail > Preferences > Composing and see if you have "Automatically Cc (or some other selection) myself" selected and unselect it if you do.

[image: Mail composing preferences]

Comment: I don't have that option checked, but I still get an e-mail. There is some sort of an alias system, though. I'll contact our system administrator. Thanks!